# Error mysqlclient en cloudLinux

Tags: python, flask

estoy intentando instalar mi aplicación flask en un cpanel con CloudLinux. He visto que a bastante gente le genera errores estas librerias, pero no he visto que suceda en un Linux como el mio y no tengo muy claro como hacerlo, aquí os dejo mi problema. Cuando entro en el entorno virtual y escribo `pip install mysqlclient` sale el siguiente error:
(En windows también me pasaba pero descargué una extensión de aquí `https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient` y solucionado)

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/clouxlla/virtualenv/flask/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import                                                                                                              sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlcli                                                                                                             ent/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/setup.py'                                                                                                             "'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('                                                                                                             "'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'                                                                                                             "'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-opkxp_ee
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/
  Complete output (29 lines):
  /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown                                                                                                              distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/co                                                                                                             nstants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/cons                                                                                                             tants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constant                                                                                                             s
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constant                                                                                                             s
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/                                                                                                             constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/consta                                                                                                             nts
  running build_ext
  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
  /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compa                                                                                                             re -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURC                                                                                                             E -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.1 -I/us                                                                                                             r/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c                                                                                                              MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
  unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or dir                                                                                                             ectory
  error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status                                                                                                              1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient

DEPRECATION: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient which do not use PEP 517. pip will fall back to legacy 'setup.py install' for these. pip 21.0 will remove support for this functionality. A possible replacement is to fix the wheel build issue reported above. You can find discussion regarding this at https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8368.

 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/clouxlla/virtualenv/flask/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jckn3ad2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/clouxlla/virtualenv/flask/3.8/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/
    Complete output (29 lines):
    /opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/distutils/dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
    creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb
    /opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,1,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.1 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/.. -I/opt/alt/python38/include/python3.8 -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/MySQLdb/_mysql.o
    unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory
    error: command '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/clouxlla/virtualenv/flask/3.8/bin/python3.8_bin -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-oenqn_iu/mysqlclient/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-jckn3ad2/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/clouxlla/virtualenv/flask/3.8/include/site/python3.8/mysqlclient Check the logs for full command output.
```

En caso de intentar instalar flask-mysqldb que también lo necesito me surge un error también.
¿Puedo ponerme en contacto con el ticket de soporte de CloudLinux, o qué debo hacer?
¿Qué debo hacer? Gracias a todos de antemano.

Comment: En una de las líneas dice `unable to execute '/opt/rh/devtoolset-7/root/usr/bin/gcc': No such file or directory`. ¿Tenés instalado `devtoolset-7`?

Comment: @padaleiana No, no lo tengo instalado, hay alguna documentación para instalarlo en CloudLinux?

Comment: Buscando rápidamente no encontré algo relacionado en la documentación, pero como CloudLinux está basado en CentOS, las mismas instrucciones deberían servirte.
Si llegás a instalarlo y luego sigue sin funcionar, por favor, editá la pregunta agregando lo que ya intentaste y si es que otros errores aparecieron.

Comment: @padaleiana El problema es que tengo un hosting de namecheap el cual no me deja alterar el software. Y tengo que instalar un paquete .rpm. Tienes otra idea?

Comment: Antes de ejecutar `pip install mysqlclient`, ¿ejecutaste `sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel`? (Basándome en lo que dice [la página del proyecto](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/))

Comment: @padaleiana No puedo usar ese tipo de comandos, pero ya lo he arreglado, he cambiado la versión y ya funciona

Comment: Genial! Agregalo como respuesta, para ayudar a otros usuarios más adelante :)

Comment: @padaleiana ahí está mi respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema es que mi hosting no aportaba el acceso root, en caso de que lo tengas, la solución puedes estar aquí. https://github.com/openai/gym/issues/757
Yo simplemente puse una versión inferior, la 3.5.9 en contreto y ya funcionaba.